# Unicode in batch

Tags: windows, batch, unicode

My question is simple.
I need to put fancy unicode into a batch file. I already put `chcp 65001` at the start.

Here is my example code:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 >NUL
echo [✓] This is a correct line
echo [✗] This is an incorrect line
pause
```

This is the output:

[image: Unicode Output]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I eventiualy realised what is the problem.
To run batch files with proper unicode you need to use Windows Terminal (You can find it on Microsoft Store)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).